# How to fit Weibull distribution using "MME" method and find the estimates in R

Tags: r, distributions, estimators, weibull-distribution

I am trying to fit a Weibull distribution using Moments Matching Estimation (MME) method. Specifically I am trying to estimate the shape parameter $k$ and the
scale $\lambda$.

I am currently using R and the package *fitdistrplus*.  Below is the code used to fit the weibull distribution in R from the fitdistrplus and actuar package.

```
a <- rweibull(100, 10,1)
weibul_mme <- mmedist(a, "weibull", order = 1:2)
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Error in mmedist(a, "weibull", order = 1:2) : 
  the empirical moment function must be defined
```

It would be helpful if anyone can tell me what mistake I am making or provide some reading material for the same.

Comment: This is the wrong site for R question, go to Stack Overflow. Note that to get anyone to consider your question at that site you need to provide what is called a "reproducible example". And post the error message.

Comment: @StopClosingQuestionsFast I have edited the question, is it fine now?

Comment: Sorry missed that you actually generated data. Yes i think it is fine. I will look it since it has not been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Weibull distribution is defined as

$$f(x) = \left\{ \frac{k}{\lambda} \left( \frac{x}{\lambda} \right)^{k-1} \exp\left( - \frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k \right\} \ \ \ \mbox{for} \ \  x\geq 0$$

and the raw moments are given as

$$m_j(\lambda,k) := \mathbb E[X^j] = \lambda^j \Gamma\left(1  +\frac{j}{k}\right),$$

where $\Gamma(.)$ is the Gamma function [(Wiki on Weibull distribution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).

To estimate the parameters $\theta := (\lambda,k)$ using a random sample $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of draws from the Weibull distribution it is first noted that the raw moments are a function of the parameters $\theta$. Given a guess of parameters the raw moments can therefore be calculated and can be compared to the raw sample moments defined as

$$ \bar x^j := \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^j.$$

By the Law of Large Numbers the sample moments should match the theoretical moments $m_j(\theta) = m_j(\lambda,k)$. This motivates the method of trying to find the correct parameters $\theta_0 = (\lambda_0,k_0)$ by minimizing sum of squared errors

$$Q(\lambda,k) =  \sum_j \sum_i (m_j(\lambda,k) - x_i^j)^2.$$

This type of estimator can be justified within method of moments set up, general method of moments, extremum estimator (see for example Newey and McFadden (1994) *Large Sample Estimation and Hypothesis Testing*).

In R this method is implemented in the *fitdistrplus* package [(fitdistrplus on CRAN)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/) with the accompanying article *fitdistrplus: An R Package for Fitting Distributions* by  Marie Laure Delignette-Muller and Christophe Dutang [(see the R journal)](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v064i04).

Here is a small sample code illustrating the use:

```
  #simulate a sample
  mysample  <-  rweibull(1000, 3, 1)

  #function to calculate sample raw moment
  memp  <-  function(x, order) mean(x^order)

  #fit by MME
  mmedist(mysample, "weibull", order=c(1, 2), memp=memp, 
    start=list(shape=10, scale=10), lower=0, upper=Inf)
```

The code works by using the function `memp` to calculate the raw sample moments of some order $j$ based on the sample `mysample`. This is then matched with the theoretical moment using numerical optimization solving

$$\min_{\lambda,k} Q(\lambda,k),$$

using the solver `optim` according to package documentation.

Comment: The only thing which I did not understand in the above code is `memp  <-  function(x, order) mean(x^order)`. Could you kindly explain what this code does?